# Can a parent process change its child's environment?

Tags: linux, process, environment-variables

When looking at some examples for implementing a FastCGI client I ran into some curious code.

```c
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
        printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
               "Got a <i>%s</i> request\n",
               getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"));
    return 0;
}
```

To me that looks like the process would always get the same value for `getenv(...)`, but it seems like the intent is to read data from the parent process.

Can the parent process update the child environment while the child process is running?

Comment: No. Why would the server name change?

Comment: Just looks like less than ideal programming where instead the SERVER_NAME value should be stored statically/globally or some such.

Comment: I saw a couple of other examples as well, but the `SERVER_NAME` variant was to shortest. Updated to better show that the intent was to read data from parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

But the `FCGI_Accept()` function can update (the C library's copy of) the current process' environment every time that it is called, which of course is what it does.

Indeed, not retaining the result of calling `getenv()` is *specifically* called out in the doco of that function.  So you can count how many people on this page read the doco.  (-:

## Further reading

- [`FCGI_Accept`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/FastCGI/FastCGI-4/fcgi/doc/FCGI_Accept.3).  *FCGI Manual*.  Open Market, Inc..  1996.  Archived at opensource.apple.com.

Comment: The edited version of the question provides significantly more incentive to read the documentation than the original ;-).